# Django if/else tag

Tags: python, django, templates, if-statement

I have no idea why i receive "The result is False"
What is wrong with the code?

```
x = True
t = Template("""
    {% if x %}
        The result is True.
    {% else %}
        The result is False.
    {% endif %}
    """)
c = Context()
html = t.render(c)
return HttpResponse(html)
```

Regards

Answer (score 5):

You're not including the `x` in the context:

```
c = Context()
```

You should do:

```
c = Context({'x': x})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `x` is define in python file, not in template file.

so, `x` is None, you got `The result is False.` is right.

you can

`c = Context({'x': x})`

trans `x` to template file.

and you can see this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/